# Installing Jupyter Notebook python package - version confusion

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I usually work with pyCharm in which it is really easy to manage different python versions. (I use High Sierra, Mac)

In my settings I can see all of them and addon packages:

[image]

To be honest, I don't remember how I installed all of these, a bunch of them through brew though.

Now I am trying to run a Jupyter Notebook in python 3, it's using the python 3 kernel, but I am missing acp package.

So I pip install acp. ok.

The Notebook doesn't see the package. This makes me think it's not installing in the correct python version.

pip3 is not recognised as a command. 
brew install python3 -> asks to update python 2 to version 3 (which I don't want).

I am quite confused now as how to intall the packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be installing with python executable your jupyter is not using.
you can directly install in jupyter shell by allowing python executable your jupyter is using:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install acp
```

Comment: Thanks! acp installed, however, my script outputs 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'acp.common', when doing your method for acp.common, it gives: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement acp.common (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for acp.common

Comment: I ended up avoiding this package. But it works great to install normal packages!

Answer (score 1):

To check your Python executables, you may open a terminal and type

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you will know which path your python exists in. Make sure to select the same path when you configure your project interpreter. Then you may like to upgrade your pip by typing in a terminal:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version
```

Make sure python version is >3, after which that you may try:

```
pip3 install acp
```